# Xamarin Android app crashes when using GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android

Im following the tutorial to add Google Cloud Messaging to your xamarin android project ([Walkthrough - Using Remote Notifications in Xamarin.Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/)).

But im having trouble trying to connect to Google Services. 
Everytime i try to build/ run my app, Visual Studio just trys to launch the app but then stops about a second later.

Heres the output message:

> Android application is debugging. The application could not be
>   started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target
>   device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).
>
> Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this
>   project is set to Deploy for this configuration.

Here is my manifest file also:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="PushNotificationsAndroid.PushNotificationsAndroid" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" 
          android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <user-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <permission android:name="PushNotificationsAndroid.PushNotificationsAndroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
              android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="PushNotificationsAndroid.PushNotificationsAndroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application android:label="PushNotificationsAndroid"></application>
</manifest>
```

I commented out some of the permission lines and this issue seems just to happen when i added the line:

```
<permission android:name="PushNotificationsAndroid.PushNotificationsAndroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
              android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Can anyone give me some advice to why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that there are no other apps installed that declares a permission with the same name? From the documentation: _"The system does not allow multiple packages to declare a permission with the same name, unless all the packages are signed with the same certificate. If a package declares a permission, the system does not permit the user to install other packages with the same permission name, unless those packages are signed with the same certificate as the first package."_

Comment: ..continued: _"To avoid naming collisions, we recommend using reverse-domain-style naming for custom permissions, for example `com.example.myapp.ENGAGE_HYPERSPACE`."_

Comment: I have changed my package name to **com.notifications.PushNotificationsAndroid** and it still doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution. I just had to make the package name lowercase for some reason

> com.notifications.pushnotificationsandroid

Comment: wow, thankyou, that worked for me.. you must be the only person on the net with this solution, thankyou i can now move on.. kodos to you